# How Can I Remove Dimensions in AWS Timestream Table through query editor?

Tags: amazon-timestream

I am trying to remove dimensions from an AWS Timestream Table through the query editor with the following query

```sql
Alter table "RawData" Drop Column "SupplierId" 
Where "SupplierId" is Dimension column in Table "RawData"
```

But I'm getting error for `invalid query syntax at line 12`. I was trying this, but was not able to Drop Dimensions Column

Answer (score 0):

SQL statements in Timestream are read-only. ALTER table statements are not allowed in syntax.  Also: Amazon Timestream uses a dynamic schema, that is created when data is ingested. Once a column is dynamically created it will stay there even if no data is ingested for this column and all older records are deleted